# Manifolds up to homeomorphisms VS Manifolds up to homotopy equivalence

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $\mathcal{Man}$ be the set of all connected closed orientable manifolds **up to homeomorphism**. It is an abelian semigroup with respect to the cartesian product $\times$ (multiplication) and unit $\ast$ (zero dimensional manifold ).

In the same way lets define  $\mathcal{Man}^{h}$ as the set of all connected closed orientable manifolds **up to homotopy equivalence**. It is an abelian semigroup with respect to the cartesian product $\times$ (multiplication) and unit $\ast$ (zero dimensional manifold ).

There is an evident (surjective) homomorphism of abelian semigroups :

$$i:\mathcal{M}\rightarrow \mathcal{M}^{h}  $$
$$M\mapsto M $$

which induces a homomorphism of abelian groups after group completion (Grothendieck construction).
$$K(i):K(\mathcal{Man})\rightarrow K(\mathcal{Man}^{h}) $$

I do believe that my questions are naive, but let me try to ask them:

1. Is there some (partial) understanding of the groups  $K(\mathcal{Man})$ and $ K(\mathcal{Man}^{h})$ ? (e.g. Do they have torsion elements? what are other relations...?)
2. Is there some (partial) understanding of the Kernel of the map $K(i)$ ? (torsion elements, generators, other relations,...)

**First Edit:** let me ask a more direct question: suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are connected closed orientable manifolds such that $X\times X$ is homeomorphic to $Y\times Y$, is $X$ homeomorphic to $Y$, or is there a counterexample?

**Second Edit (Motivation):** I'm not a specialist of this field, but reading some articles and some questions/answers in mathoverflow, it seems to me that lots of conjecture and theorems can be reformulated in the setting of the abelian semigroups $\mathcal{Man}$ and $\mathcal{Man}^{h}$.

- The semigroups $\mathcal{Man}^{h}$ and $\mathcal{Man}$ do not have cancellation property: the equation $a+b=a+c$ does not imply that $b=c$ in general.
- the semigroup $\mathcal{Man}$ does have torsion elements (Lens spaces $L(7,1)$ and $L(7,2)$), I do believe that $\mathcal{Man}^{h}$ does have also torsion elements.
- Let $T^{1}$ be the torus of dimension 1 (circle). Let $\mathcal{T} \subset \mathcal{Man}$ be the smallest subsemigroup containing $T^1$ and all $M$ such that $M$ is homotopy equivalent to $T^{n}$ for some natural number $n$. If we can prove that $(\mathcal{T},\times,\ast) $ is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{N},+,0)$ then the Poincare conjecture follows in dimension 3 (because it will imply that if $T^3$ is homotopy equivalent to $M$ then $T^3$ is homeomorphic to $M$).
- The Borel conjecture can be formulated as follows:
  Let $\mathcal{Man}_{aspherical}$ be the subsemigroup generated by aspherical closed connected orientable manifolds and let Let $\mathcal{Man}_{aspherical}^{h}$ be the subsemigroup generated by aspherical closed connected orientable manifolds (up to homotopy equivalence) then the Borel conjecture is true if
  the natural homomorphism $\mathcal{Man}_{aspherical}\rightarrow \mathcal{Man}_{aspherical}^{h} $ is an isomorphism.
- In general it is very hard to work with semigroups even if they are abelian. For all these reasons, it seems that is reasonable to pass to the Grothendieck construction and study the associated abelian groupes, of course some important information will be lost (the failure of the cancelation property).

Comment: Side note: an abelian semigroup with a unit is usually called a commutative monoid (semigroups do not require an identity element. I don’t know why “abelian” did not catch on for semigroups/monoids.)

Comment: The first step to understanding 2 is using surgery theory to classify manifolds in the homotopy type of $M$. The next step I presume would be understanding cancellation phenomena of manifolds and how it differs when one moves from homeomorphism to homotopy equivalence.

Comment: There is some partial understanding.  For example, the Poincare Polynomial is a homomorphism to symmetric polynomials, so when you pass to the group completion you get a homomorphism to the rational symmetric polynomials.  That is a fairly coarse invariant.  But it gives you some constraints on the kernel.

Comment: In between the two abelian semigroups in the question, one could consider $\mathcal{M}an^{th}$ defined as manifolds up to homotopy equivalence over $BO$.  Maybe Proposition 3.3 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.03186.pdf) can be used to show that $K(\mathcal{M}an) \to K(\mathcal{M}an^{th})$ is an isomorphism?  I'm not sure how to proceed from there though, but at least it would be "purely homotopy theory".

Comment: The previous comment was about smooth manifolds and diffeomorphism, where the map to $BO$ classifies the stable tangent bundle.  For topological manifolds and homeomorphism, replace $BO$ with $BTOP$.

Comment: @user171227 Perhaps this says more about manifolds up to simple homotopy equivalence? If I recall correctly, simple homotopy equivalent is the same as stably homeomorphic with respect to $[0,1]$.

Comment: @ConnorMalin I think $S^1$ and $[0,1]$ behave quite differently: for instance, any homotopy equivalence becomes a simple homotopy equivalence after crossing with $S^1$, see Theorem 23.2 in _A Course in Simple Homotopy Theory_ by M. Cohen.

Comment: Lens spaces give counterexamples to your question. I think X = L(7,1) and L(7,2) work.

Comment: @mme thanks, so that means that $K(Man)$ does have torsion elements!

Comment: I don't agree. It says that 2X = 2Y, so that X - Y is 2-torsion. But X - Y could be zero in your Grothendieck group. In my explicit example, I believe it is (these should be homeomorphic after crossing with a 3-sphere).

Comment: @mme I think you are right, thanks

Comment: @Ryan Just to be sure, you mean symmetric polynomials in the sense that the coefficients form a symmetric sequence, and we have just one variable? With rational polynomials you mean rational functions? And is there already something which shows that the K-group is more than that?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: correct.  I suspect that's not the entire group completion.  Presumably the total Stiefel-Whitney class of the tangent bundle would give some independent elements for the "manifolds up to homeomorphism" version of the question.  I would imagine a chain of similar invariants coming from surgury theory.

Comment: @ConnorMalin a map between finite complexes is a simple homotopy equivalence if and only if it becomes homotopic to a homeomorphism after crossing with the Hilbert cube. But crossing with a finite number of intervals destroys much less information. In particular, Pontrjagin classes are an obstruction to homemorphism preserved by crossing with the interval.

Comment: Experience says that the problem is more coherent if you don't decategorify so early. Don't consider spaces up to homotopy equivalence, but consider specific homotopy eq. The structure set $S(X)$ is the set of manifolds with a homotopy eq to $X$ up to homeo $M\to M'$ that commute up to homotopy with the equivalences to $X$. The homotopy eqs of $X$ act on the structure set your object is the quotient. In particular, the Borel conjecture is that every homotopy equivalence between aspherical manifolds is homotopic to a homeomorphism, which is not obviously implied by your statement.

Comment: Mazur stabilized by multiplying by open intervals, leaving only the stable tangent bundle. Stabilizing by multiplying by the closed interval is the subject of pseudoisotopy theory, which is related to $K$-theory. Crossing with a manifold of multiplies $K$-theory by the Euler characteristic, so stabilizing by multiplying by $S^1$ or other odd sphere might be interesting with a tractable simplification. I suspect stabilizing with arbitrary manifolds doesn't destroy more